# How can I have Windows and Ubuntu on my computer?

Tags: windows

I have Linux Mint on my computer and wondering how I can get Windows on here as well. I saw one saying to use Grub except I have no idea how to use it. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Since you don't have either operating systems on the system,  follow this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Installing_Windows_After_Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two partitions on your disk (three if you want swap partition for ubuntu into a different partition than the OS's).
You install windows on one partition and ubuntu on the other.
I suggest this order because in my experience windows installs his bootloader without asking the user if he wants to, and this would overwrite grub installed by ubuntu.
You can always restore grub, but it's faster if you do not have to!
Suppose you have installed ubuntu and windows and grub, then you boot up ubuntu, open a terminal and type 
`sudo update-grub` or `sudo update-grub2` (depends on your version). 
Now grub should find windows and allow you to boot windows from the grub menu!

Comment: So you're saying on my first partition I should put Windows then on my second partition I should put Ubuntu. Then bootup up with the second partition (Ubuntu) and Install grub. Then do that command in terminal then I should be able to bootup with whatever one I want?

Comment: Not exactly. You can install them in any partition you want (you can do any number of partitions). The important is that you install first windows, grub will be installed during ubuntu installation (it will prompt you if to, and you'll say yes). If you do otherwise ubuntu will install grub, but the following windows installation will overwrite it with its own bootloader, that does not recognise ubuntu. Once you installed them (first windows in any partition, then ubuntu in another) your computer should boot ubuntu with grub. Then, in ubuntu, you'll give that command to make grub see windows.